# Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index' in "flutter"

Tags: json, flutter, dio

I convert my json to class, and wanna use get.dio() method. I get the error "Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'. How can I solve it?

That's my class.

```
 class Word {
Word({
String? kelime,
String? anlami,
}) {
_kelime = kelime;
_anlami = anlami;
}

Word.fromJson(dynamic json) {
_kelime = json['kelime'];
_anlami = json['anlami'];
}
String? _kelime;
String? _anlami;
Word copyWith({
  String? kelime,
  String? anlami,
 }) =>
  Word(
    kelime: kelime ?? _kelime,
    anlami: anlami ?? _anlami,
  );
String? get kelime => _kelime;
String? get anlami => _anlami;

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
final map = <String, dynamic>{};
map['kelime'] = _kelime;
map['anlami'] = _anlami;
return map;
```

}
}

and these are my getting codes.

```
Word wordData = Word();

@override
void initState() {
 super.initState();
    getWordData();
    setState(() {});
 });
}

getWordData() async {
  var dio = Dio();
  var responce = await dio.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/saturu/turkish_dictionary/main/4_letter.json");
  wordData = Word.fromJson(responce.data);
  print(wordData);
}
```

Comment: where is error show? and also share your widget file

Comment: no more widget that's my homepage, it's a stateful widget actually, wordData = Word.fromJson(responce.data); makes the error :(

Comment: yes. the error is here,  wordData = Word.fromJson(responce.data); it is a list of map you are getting from api.     `List<Word> wordData = [];`//define first this

`wordData = (responce.data as List).map((val)=> Word.fromJson(val));` //change  `print(wordData);` //print

Comment: A value of type 'Iterable<Word>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<Word>'.says the code again

Comment: check below. I made a change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import 'dart:convert'; //import this

List<Word> wordData = []; //declare


getWordData() async {
  var dio = Dio();
  var responce = await dio.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/saturu/turkish_dictionary/main/4_letter.json");
  wordData =(json.decode(response.body) as List).map((val) => Word.fromJson(val)).toList();
  print(wordData);
}
```

Comment: thank you Brook, I got the list this time but with a little mistake, the items in list seems as Instance of 'Word, sorry for asking much, im almost new in coding. I think we are so close!

Comment: Yes. it is an instance of Word. If you print `print(wordData[0].kelime)` you will get the actual value of the list of the first element

Comment: ok. you welcome. accept my answer it will be useful for other people

Answer (score 0):

The api returns a list of words, List. u can modify the code as follows

```dart
List<Word> wordData = [];

@override
void initState() {
 super.initState();
    getWordData();
    setState(() {});
 });
}

getWordData() async {
  final dio = Dio();
  final response = await dio.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/saturu/turkish_dictionary/main/4_letter.json");
  wordData = List.from(response).map((word)=> Word.fromJson(word)).toList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [URL](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/saturu/turkish_dictionary/main/4_letter.json) is returning a list of maps, and you are trying to assign the list to the model `Word`.

I think you need to update the widget as

```html
List<Word> wordData = [];

@override
void initState() {
 super.initState();
    getWordData();
 });
}

getWordData() async {
  var dio = Dio();
  var responce = await dio.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/saturu/turkish_dictionary/main/4_letter.json");
  wordData = jsonDecode(responce.data).map((e)=> Word.fromJson(e)).toList();
    setState(() {});
}
```

Comment: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast, it gives this error right now

Comment: then i think you have to convert the string to json object